# Why is my linux command with awk not working

Tags: linux, bash, awk

i am trying to let this command work but it won't let me do anything

```
awk -F: ‘{if($3>'1000') print$1}’ passwd | sort > users.txt
```

I get an error which is saying:

```
bash: syntaxfout nabij onverwacht symbool '('
```

Can someone help me out?

Comment: Please provide an explanation as to what exactly you are trying to achieve. Following the guide at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask will help you maximise your chances at getting an answer.

Comment: I looks like you're using the wrong quote symbol.  The character preceding the `{` should be `'`

Answer (score 3):

You're using `‘` instead of `'`. And then, you should replace `'` with `"` in the awk program (or just leave them out):

```
awk -F: '{if ($3 > 1000) print $1}' passw | ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using backticks instead of single quotes.  Try:

```
awk -F: '{if($3>1000) print $1} passwd | sort > users.txt
```

or just

```
awk -F: '$3>1000 {print $1}' passwd | sort > users.txt
```

Comment: Actually, the `‘` chars aren't backticks but some sort of quotation marks used in e. g. English and Dutch. Products like Microsoft Word usually replace `'` by these language specific symbols, usually for people who find these programs are a good multi-clipboard tool :-/ If they were actual backticks, Bash would try to execute `{if($3>'1000') print$1}'.